# Intersect bigram trigram in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a bigram and I have a trigram, how can I match a bigram that is in the trigram in python?

I have tried examples but I do not understand because I'm newbie, thank you very much.

```
Bigram = [('red', 'car'), ('new', 'york'), ('table', 'window')]
Trigram = [('red', 'car','expensive,), ('new', 'york','city')]
```

Result: `[('red', 'car'),('new', 'york')]`

Comment: Your desired results don't make much sense to me. Why do you expect `('red', 'car')` to be matched but not `('new', 'york')`? You mention examples, but don't show any of them, we can't explain code we can't see, so you're unlikely to get an suitable answer as the question currently stands.

Comment: It is true, the output must show New York, I was confused when writing, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use sets to get the intersection by converting your trigrams into bigrams in a list comprehension:

```
Bigram = [('red', 'car'), ('new', 'york'), ('table', 'window')]
Trigram = [('red', 'car','expensive'), ('new', 'york','city')]

set(Bigram).intersection( (a,b) for x,y,z in Trigram for a,b in ([x,y],[y,z]) )

# {('new', 'york'), ('red', 'car')}
```